# Error using tf.image.decode_image " b'Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tensorflow

```
    image_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('img.jpeg', 'link') #'link' in my code is replaces with a alink to a google drive image
    image_raw = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_image(image_raw)
```

This code is part of a code that I found online to generate adversarial examples. In the original code they pass a link to `tf.keras.utils.get_file` of an online image, and running it makes no errors. However, when I replace it with a link to an image on my google drive I get this error `InvalidArgumentError: Expected"tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP'" referring to tf.image.decode_image`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are not using a direct download link, and therefore, your file is not getting downloaded. Here is a site to create a direct download link from Drive: https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/home

Comment: Please mark my answer as the solution then please, I am new to stackoverflow and really need the reputation. Thanks.